# Cassandra Thrift Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: cassandra, thrift

i encounter a problem when inserting a large value to a column, the value `byte[]`
 length is 25130744 (converted from `DataSet` to `byte[]`), and gives me an exception: `IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

Anyone know the reason? Small column values work fine. Are there some data size limit or request timeout limit in Aquiles or Cassandra server?

```
Cassandra version: 1.0.2, Aquiles version: 1.0, .NET Framework 4.0
```

Here is the detailed info:

```
Server Error in '/test' Application.

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Source Error: 


Line 482: public void recv_insert()
Line 483: {
Line 484: TMessage msg = iprot_.ReadMessageBegin();
Line 485: if (msg.Type == TMessageType.Exception) {
Line 486: TApplicationException x = TApplicationException.Read(iprot_);

Source File: D:\codeplex\Aquiles\trunk\Aquiles.Cassandra10\Apache\Cassandra\Cassandra.cs Line: 484 

Stack Trace: 


[SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +245

[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.]
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +7768653
Thrift.Transport.TStreamTransport.Read(Byte[] buf, Int32 off, Int32 len) in d:\thrift-0.6.0\thrift-0.6.0\lib\csharp\src\Transport\TStreamTransport.cs:84
Thrift.Transport.TTransport.ReadAll(Byte[] buf, Int32 off, Int32 len) in d:\thrift-0.6.0\thrift-0.6.0\lib\csharp\src\Transport\TTransport.cs:54
Thrift.Transport.TFramedTransport.ReadFrame() in d:\thrift-0.6.0\thrift-0.6.0\lib\csharp\src\Transport\TFramedTransport.cs:90
Thrift.Transport.TFramedTransport.Read(Byte[] buf, Int32 off, Int32 len) in d:\thrift-0.6.0\thrift-0.6.0\lib\csharp\src\Transport\TFramedTransport.cs:83
Thrift.Transport.TTransport.ReadAll(Byte[] buf, Int32 off, Int32 len) in d:\thrift-0.6.0\thrift-0.6.0\lib\csharp\src\Transport\TTransport.cs:54
Thrift.Protocol.TBinaryProtocol.ReadI32() in d:\thrift-0.6.0\thrift-0.6.0\lib\csharp\src\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol.cs:338
Thrift.Protocol.TBinaryProtocol.ReadMessageBegin() in d:\thrift-0.6.0\thrift-0.6.0\lib\csharp\src\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol.cs:220
Apache.Cassandra.Client.recv_insert() in D:\codeplex\Aquiles\trunk\Aquiles.Cassandra10\Apache\Cassandra\Cassandra.cs:484
DataAccessLib.CassandraAccess.<>c__DisplayClass28.<InsertCommand>b__27(Client client) in C:\TestProject\Class1.cs:746

[ExecutionBlockException: Exception 'Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.' during executing command. See inner exception for further details.]
Aquiles.Core.Cluster.Impl.DefaultCluster.Execute(Delegate executionBlock, String keyspaceName, ConnectionConfig overrideConnectionConfig) in D:\codeplex\Aquiles\trunk\Aquiles.Core\Cluster\Impl\DefaultCluster.cs:191
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a setting in cassandra.yaml that controls the maximum thrift message size. It defaults to 16 megabytes.

```
thrift_max_message_length_in_mb: 16
```

You can update that setting in order to send larger messages. Keep in mind that the setting applies to the entire message including some overhead, so you will need to set it higher than the actual size of the column you are sending.

Theoretically you can increase this setting to the gigabyte range, but it is almost certainly not a good idea. The entire thrift message is going to need to fit in memory and the default rpc timeout settings may also have to be changed.

I would consider chunking your column into smaller sub columns rather than increasing that setting.